Docker in docker
В рамках Multistage сборки, процесс build, mvn во время сборки проекта вызывает ещё один докер контейнер (postgres).
FROM maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-21-alpine as build

COPY src src
COPY pom.xml pom.xml

VOLUME var/run/docker.sock
RUN ["mvn", "clean", "install", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"]

FROM bellsoft/liberica-openjre-alpine:21.0.3
COPY /target/demo.jar .

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "demo.jar"]

При сборке получаю ошибку:
failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Found docker unix domain socket but file mode was not as expected (expected: srwxr-xr-x).

К сожалению платформа с которой я деплою приложение не позволяет кастомизировать вызов Dockerfile, поэтому приходится все инструкции описывать в нем
Подскажите кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и какие пути решения тут есть

А ты слэш в VOLUME случайно не забыл?
